# What earth is (zombie body / Spanish speaking) Stephen Strange from?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

There are three Stephen Stranges in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*:

1. Stephen Strange from Earth-616 (travels with America Chavez)
2. Stephen Strange from Earth-838 (Illuminati Strange; killed by Black Bolt)
3. Stephen Strange (zombie body / Spanish speaking)

What Earth is the third Stephen Strange from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is referred to as Defender Strange by fans and media also Defender Strange's outfit is a reference to Doctor Strange's appearance in [2012's Defenders comic series](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Defenders_Vol_4).

For which earth it belongs to, Raimi himself revealed it:

> On the film's audio commentary, Raimi revealed that the gray-templed Stephen Strange variant hails from Earth-617, the multiversal next-door neighbor of the Marvel Cinematic Universe, which is set on Earth-616. - [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/multiverse-of-madness-defender-stranger-earth-617-mcu/)

Comment: The official subtitles also identify him as "Defender Strange".